# Sending multipart/mixed http request to an asp.net web api controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'd like to send a multipart/mixed http request ($batch) to an asp.net web api controller, as follows:

```
--batch_fb0c-6847-2810
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_08b4-5b66-0d79

--changeset_08b4-5b66-0d79
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST People HTTP/1.1
Content-Id: 1
Accept: application/atomsvc+xml;q=0.8, application/json;odata=fullmetadata;q=0.7,                 application/json;q=0.5, */*;q=0.1
DataServiceVersion: 1.0
Content-Type: application/json
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0

{"Id":1,"Task":"1","DueDate":"2013-02-    21T11:34:06.247","Completed":false,"University":1,"Degree":1}
--changeset_08b4-5b66-0d79
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST People HTTP/1.1
Content-Id: 2
Accept: application/atomsvc+xml;q=0.8, application/json;odata=fullmetadata;q=0.7,     application/json;q=0.5, */*;q=0.1
DataServiceVersion: 1.0
Content-Type: application/json
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0

{"Id":4,"Task":"2","DueDate":"2013-02-21T11:34:06.247","Completed":false,"University":4,"Degree":4}

--changeset_08b4-5b66-0d79--

--batch_fb0c-6847-2810--
```

The problem is my request is not routed to proper action in my controller, is there any solution out there to accomplish this issue?!

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is outdated.  Batch support has been added to the Web API project, complete documentation is here:

https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Web+API+Request+Batching

Comment: Hello, Although Batch support has been added, there's a gnarly bug in the .NET framework I believe which doesn't parse multi-part requests that do not end with CRLF (or \r\n) correctly. This happens when using POSTMAN. We always get the following error: Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete. Any thoughts?